# How to query by array length in Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Is there a way to query by array length in Parse?
i.e. I want to get all the objects where the array length > 2 or something like that.

Thanks!

Comment: You will have to give more details. As it is it isn't really possible to comment because we have no context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct way to do that. But what you could do is, adding another row which you use as a counter. Check the [`beforeSave`](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-onsave) documentation for that. For example everytime you add elements to the array, you increase the counter. Than you could check the size like that:

```
//Shows all items where the arraySize is bigger than 10
yourQuery.whereKey("arraySize", greaterThan: 10)
```

Comment: @Wain Thx. I've added that to my answer.